# How to diagnose HMC results like r-hat for a Mixture Model?

Tags: mixed-model, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, diagnostic, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I have the following distribution $$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol \pi&\sim\text{Dirichlet}([1,\cdots 1]\in R^K)\\
\boldsymbol \theta&\sim P(\boldsymbol \theta)
\\
\mathbf y&\sim \sum _{i=1}^K\pi_i\text{Joint}(\theta_k)
\end{align}
$$
This is a Bayesian Mixture Model specified by the mixing weights $\pi_i$, paramaters $\theta_i$, and number of components $K$.

After sampling 5 chains from an HMC, the samples for $\boldsymbol \pi\in R^{5\times K}$ is **not identifiable**.
In other words, if there are three dominant values for $\pi_i,\pi_j,\pi_k$ when $K=5$, these three dominants would be jumbled in different combinations.

This would cause MCMC diagnostics like r hat to give wrong values. In fact, MCMC diagnostics would give a nearly uniform distribution as the mean of the HMC sampled $\boldsymbol \pi$.

---

How do I perform diagnostics? Do i simply run a single but very large number of chain samples and split these ?

For example, sample $1000$ samples using an HMC sampler and split these into five $200$ samples and pass these into a MCMC diagnostics function?

Comment: Have you looked up the 'label switching problem' for mixture models?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer, but in general you can go a long way by adding an *order constraint* to your model: enforcing $\theta_1 \lt \theta_2 \lt\dots\lt \theta_k$.  This is trickier to do if $\theta$ is multidimensional ([forum](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/other-constraints-than-mean-ordering-to-identify-mixture-model/17945)).

You can find more on this in the [stan docs](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/label-switching-problematic.html). [This guide](https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/identifying_mixture_models.html) is also useful, but quite technical.

Comment: May I ask if you know any bijectors that will enforce that constant? I'll lookup the mentioned forums for the meantime.

Comment: I found a TFP Ascending bijector which I will then chain with a Softmax. I'll try placing them on top of the Dirichlet distribution. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how in Tensorflow, sorry.